# ADBannerView Full Ad Orientation Not Changing

Tags: cocoa-touch, iad

I use the code right out of the Apple iAd Suite demo code to implement my banner ad with a tab bar controller. It was working fine until recently, when I noticed that the test ads became more colorful, and not just black rectangles with the words "test ad" in them.

However, I am now seeing that, while the banner view rotates okay, the full ad is only showing  in landscape orientation. The rest of the app rotates okay, but no matter what orientation the device is in, the full add only shows in landscape.

I don't see how to control this.

Here is the code:

```
#import "BannerViewController.h"

NSString * const BannerViewActionWillBegin = @"BannerViewActionWillBegin";
NSString * const BannerViewActionDidFinish = @"BannerViewActionDidFinish";

@implementation BannerViewController
{
    ADBannerView *_bannerView;
    UIViewController *_contentController;
}

- (id)initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)contentController
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
        _bannerView.delegate = self;
        _contentController = contentController;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [contentView addSubview:_bannerView];
    [self addChildViewController:_contentController];
    [contentView addSubview:_contentController.view];
    [_contentController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    self.view = contentView;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return [_contentController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    } else {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
    if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {
        contentFrame.size.height -= _bannerView.frame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    } else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }
    _contentController.view.frame = contentFrame;
    _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:BannerViewActionWillBegin object:self];
    return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:BannerViewActionDidFinish object:self];
}

@end
```

In the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method, the interfaceOrientation is portrait, and it is evaluating to true. The full ad still shows in landscape.

What is causing this and how can I control it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems only one orientation is supported in Sandboxing mode.

Comment: What is "sandboxing mode"? I've seen the term, but I'm not sure what you mean in this context. Is this for dubug and ad hoc builds only, in this case? Or does it exist in the deliverable?

Comment: Before releasing the app, that is before the app review and approval, we do testing and this is referred as sandboxing mode. Obviously debug and ad hoc builds will be in sandboxing mode.